# The equation of a line reflected about another line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

I need to find the equation of this reflected line:

[image]

Comment: Use orthogonal projection matrices and reflection matrices. Hint: the orthogonal projection of a point $x$ onto a vector $v$ is $\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}x$. The reflection of the point $x$ about the vector $v$ is $2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}x-x$.

Answer (score 7):

The General Formula for finding the equation of the line when the line $Ax+By=C$ is reflected at the line $Dx+Ey=F$.

$$y-k=\left(\frac{AE^2-AD^2-2BDE}{BE^2-BD^2+2ADE}\right)(x-h)$$
where
$$h=\frac{CD-AF}{BD-AE}$$
$$k=\frac{CE-BF}{AE-BD}$$

Where $(h,k)$ is the intersection of the lines.

If the lines are parallel, the slope becomes:

$$\frac{AE^2-AD^2-2BDE}{BE^2-BD^2+2ADE}=-\frac{A}{B}=-\frac{D}{E}$$

With equation:
$$y=-\frac{D}{E}x+\left[\frac{2F}{E}-\frac{AC\left(E^{2}+D^{2}\right)}{ED\left(A^{2}+B^{2}\right)}\right]$$

For horizontal lines $(A,D = 0)$:
$$y=\frac{2F}{E}-\frac{C}{B} $$

For vertical lines $(B,E = 0)$:
$$x=\frac{2F}{D}-\frac{C}{A} $$

This is easily derived by the use of perpendicular slopes and midpoint formula.

Comment: Are you sure of this formula? It nearly works, when applied to this situation https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4852511/109021, but the reflected lines don't have exactly the right slope (see the reflection of the orange line on the dashed orange axis)

Comment: *if the two lines are parallel then it $h=0$,$k=0$* -- But then the claimed reflection line is 

$$y=\frac{AE^2-AD^2-2BDE}{BE^2-BD^2+2ADE}x$$ 

and so goes through the origin? This doesn't seem right? E.g. the reflection of $x=5$ in $x=3$ is $x=1$ which doesn't go through the origin. Please correct me if I'm mistaken or misinterpreted what you're saying.

Comment: The formula was incomplete. The premise was to use a arbitrary line perpendicular to the parallel lines to obtain points of intersection that would be used in the midpoint formula to get a point within the reflected line. Additionally, the initial error was that $k$ was used with $x$ and $h$ with $y$. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 2):

The equation for your reflected line can be constructed using the point-slope form, $y=m(x-x_Q)+y_Q$. The point $(x_Q,y_Q)$ is easily obtained as the intersection of your "mirror" line (the blue one) and the line to be reflected (the solid red one). This leaves the problem of the slope. To get you started, recall that if a line has slope $m$ and is at an angle $\phi$ from the $x$-axis, then $m=\tan\,\phi$. You can try using the [sum/difference formulae for the tangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) to derive the slope of the reflected line (the dashed red one) from the slopes $k_n$ and $k_m$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's observe picture below. First of all note that $k_1=\tan\theta_1$ ; $k_2=\tan\theta_2$ and $k_3=\tan\theta_3$

Since dashed red line is reflection of the solid red line we may write next equality: $\alpha=\beta$ $\Rightarrow \theta_2-\theta_1=\theta_3-\theta_2$ . Now, if we apply $\tan$ on the both sides we get following: $\tan(\theta_2-\theta_1)=\tan(\theta_3-\theta_2)$ $\Rightarrow \frac{\tan\theta_2-\tan\theta_1}{1+\tan\theta_2\tan\theta_1}=\frac{\tan\theta_3-\tan\theta_2}{1+\tan\theta_3\tan\theta_2}$$\Rightarrow \frac{k_2-k_1}{1+k_2k_1}=\frac{k_3-k_2}{1+k_3k_2}$, so we can find $k_1$ from the last equation. Since $y_1=k_1x_1+C_1$ and we know that point $Z(x_q,y_q)$ belongs to the dashed red line we may write $y_1=k_1x_1+C_1$ and find $C_1$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The parametric equation of the blue line is $Z+tr_b$, where $t\in \mathbb R$ and
$r_b=(1,k_n)$, the parametric equation of the red line is $Z+tr_r$, where $t\in \mathbb R$ and
$r_r=(1,k_m)$. Then the parametric equation of the red dotted line is $Z+tr_d$, where $r_d=(r_1,r_2)$ is symmetric to $r_r$ with respect to $r_b$ and $t\in \mathbb R$. Then
$|r_d|=|r_r|$ and $(r_d,r_b)=(r_r,r_b)$. That is $r_1^2+r_2^2=1+k_m^2$ and $r_1+r_2k_n=1+k_nk_m$.
Then $(1+k_nk_m-r_2k_n)^2+r_2^2=1+k_m^2$. This is a square equation with respect to $r_2$ and
one of its roots is $k_m$. Vieta's formula implies that the other root is $r_2=\frac{k_n^2k_m+2k_n-k_m}{1+k_n^2}$. Then $r_1=1+k_nk_m-k_nr_2$.
The canonical equation of the red dotted line is $(y-Y_q)r_1=(x-X_q)r_2$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to write a proof of the formula written by William II.

When $l : Ax+By=C$ is reflected at $L : Dx+Ey=F$, the equation of the reflected line $l_r$ is given by $$\begin{cases}p(y-h)=q(x-k)&\text{if $AE\not=BD$}
\\\\x=\dfrac{2AF-CD}{AD}&\text{if $B=E=0$}
\\\\y=-\dfrac{D}{E}x+\dfrac{2BF-EC}{BE}&\text{if $AE=BD$ and $BE\not=0$}\end{cases}$$
where
$$k=\frac{CE-BF}{AE-BD},h=\frac{AF-CD}{AE-BD}$$
$$p=BE^2-BD^2+2ADE$$
$$q=AE^2-AD^2-2BDE$$

*Proof* :

**Case 1** : $AE\not=BD$ and $B\not=0$

The intersection point of $l$ with $L$ is given by $P(k,h)$.

$Q(0,\frac CB)$ is a point on $l$. Let $R(s,t)$ be the reflection point of $Q$.

Since the midpoint of $QR$ is on $L$, we have
$$D\times\frac{s}{2}+E\times\frac{\frac CB+t}{2}=F\tag1$$

Since the line $QR$ is perpendicular to $L$, we have
$$\frac{-D}{E}\times\frac{t-\frac CB}{s}=-1\tag2$$

Solving the system $(1)(2)$, we have
$$s = \frac{2 (B D F - C D E)}{B (D^2 + E^2)},t = \frac{2 B E F + C D^2 - C E^2}{B (D^2 + E^2)}$$

The equation of $l_r$, i.e. $PR$ is given by
$$y-h=\frac{t-h}{s-k}(x-k)$$
We have
$$\begin{align}\frac{t-h}{s-k}&=\frac{B(D^2+E^2)(AE-BD)(t-h)}{B(D^2+E^2)(AE-BD)(s-k)}
\\\\&=\frac{(AE^2-A D^2 - 2 B D E) (BF-C E)}{( BE^2- B D^2 +2 A D E) (B F - C E)}
\\\\&=\frac{AE^2-A D^2 - 2 B D E}{BE^2- B D^2 +2 A D E}\end{align}$$

Therefore, we finally get
$$(BE^2-BD^2+2ADE)(y-h)=(AE^2-AD^2-2BDE)(x-k)$$
(this works even when $BE^2-BD^2+2ADE=0$)

**Case 2** : $AE\not=BD$ and $B=0$

In a similar way as the one in Case 1, we see that the equation of $l_r$ is
$$2DE(y-h)=(E^2-D^2)(x-k)$$

**Case 3** : If $B=E=0$, then the equation of $l_r$ is $ADx=2AF-CD$.

**Case 4** : If $AE=BD$ and $BE\not=0$, then the equation of $l_r$ is $BDx+BEy=2BF-EC$.

Comment: (1) Are you assuming the reflection of a line in a line is a line? (2) Don't you also have to deal with the case where $B=0$?

Comment: (3) Don't you also have to deal with the case where $l$ and $L$ don't intersect?

Comment: @user182601 : Thanks. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $l$ be the line $ax+by+c=0$. Let $m$ be the line $dx+ey+f=0$. Let $r$ be the reflection of $m$ in $l$.

When we reflect an equation in $l$, to get the new equation, simply replace each $x$ with $x-2a\frac{ax+by+c}{a^{2}+b^{2}}$ and each $y$ with $y-2b\frac{ax+by+c}{a^{2}+b^{2}}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4866759/1250477)).

So, $r$ is $$d\left(x-2a\frac{ax+by+c}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\right)+e\left(y-2b\frac{ax+by+c}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\right)+f=0.$$

Or (doing a bit of algebra), $r$ is

$$\left[\left(b^{2}-a^{2}\right)d-2abe\right]x+\left[\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)e-2abd\right]y+f\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)-2c\left(ad+be\right)=0.$$