# Is the parabola the only differentiable convex even curve, such that all vertical lines, reflected on the tangent of the curve, converge into a point?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, tangent-line

- It is well known in optics that a parabola $y = x^2$ has this very important property for applications:

  $(P)$ The reflection of **all vertical lines on the tangent of the parabola all converge into a single point**

  See [Formula for the equation of the reflection of a line on another line, and application to convergence of reflections of vertical lines on a parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4852511).
  See also image 1 below.
- It is **not true** for other curves, for example for a spherical function $y = -\sqrt{1-x^2}+1$, see image 2.

**Question: is it true that the only differentiable, even, convex, functions satisfying $(P)$ are the parabolas?**

[image]

[image]

See also this about parabolas:

[image]